# Import definition for mobile connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, data-import

I have created a data extension containing phone number, ID and locale of all the contacts. I then created an import definition and mentioned this data extension as source. Till here it's fine, however I need to do this on regular basis. The data extension is automated/auto updated, how to make 'import definition' automated?

Answer (score 2):

You just add in Automation studio using the "Import Mobile Contacts" activity:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will give it a try.